# OpenCV - Not finding vertical lines with Hough Transform

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, hough-transform

I'm trying to extract data from license plates using a security camera.

I managed to use morphological operations to detect a possible ROI, but now, since the camera is placed at an angle, I need to correct the perspective before running my OCR algorithm.

When trying to use the HoughLinesP method from OpenCV, no matter how much I tweak with the input parameters, I only seem to find horizontal lines:
[image]

```
edges = cv2.Canny(ROI,50,200)

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/90, 65, minLineLength=30,lines=np.array([]), maxLineGap=10)
a,b,c = lines.shape
for i in range(a):
    cv2.line(ROI, (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), (lines[i][0][2], lines[i][0][3]), (0, 0, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imshow('houghlines',ROI)
```

Any ideia on how to get the complete plate contour via HoughLines in order to deskew the image correctly?
Thanks